# HaxeFlixel - FlxSubState unexpected null object reference

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

Im trying to make simple ingame menu. Im using FlxSubState class. First im trying invoke substate in main game state with `openSubState(gameMenu);` after pressing Esc.

There is code in my substate class, this class inheriting `FlxSubState`:

```
override public function create():Void 
{
    super.create();     
    continueButton = new FlxButton(0,0, "Continue", continueGame);
    continueButton.x = FlxG.width / 2 - continueButton.width / 2;
    continueButton.y = FlxG.height / 2 - continueButton.height / 2;
    add(continueButton);
}

private function continueGame():Void
{
    close();    
}
```

Problem is : everytime after click on `continueButton` game crash with null exception in `FlxTypedGroup`. I think its in `close();` method but i really cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me ? 
Or suggest better way to implement ingame menu ?

Comment: The code looks fine and substates is how I would do a menu. Use ```haxelib list``` to get a list of your current versions of stuff and I will try to reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by myself.
Looks like that after closing substate is destroyed. So something like this

```
override public function create():Void
{
    super.create();
    gameMenu = new MySubstate();
}
```

using with this

```
openSubState(gameMenu);
```

wont work.

Instead i need to create new substate directly

```
openSubState(new MySubstate());
```

Comment: Parent states will also have a member variable called destroySubStates. You can set that to false and the substate should not be destroyed when you close it.